# Looping through website links with R

Tags: r, web, hyperlink

I am looking to incorporate a loop in R which goes through every game's boxscore data on the NFL statistics website here: http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2012/games.htm

At the moment I am having to manually click on the "boxscore" link for every game every week; is there any way to automate this in R? My code works with the Full play-by-play dataset within each link; it's taking me ages at the moment!

Comment: Building a spider to mine the data is specifically prohibited in that site's [terms and conditions](http://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.shtml).

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise! For argument's sake, is R capable of such a thing? I have other data needs from other, open, sites.

Comment: Yes, RCurl package carries a lot of tools for web scraping. Combined with XML package, they're one fantastic duo.

Comment: @Andrie: That's not really part of the question though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster LOL at your comment and screen name :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster No it isn't, but providing an answer on how to scrape all of the data would contravene site terms, so I don't feel I can provide an answer to this question. If the OP wanted to scrape a site where this is explicitly allowed, then I may have demonstrated how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web scraping may be against the terms of use of some websites. The enforceability of these terms is unclear. While outright duplication of original expression will in many cases be illegal, in the United States the courts ruled in Feist Publications v. Rural Telephone Service that duplication of facts is allowable.

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
bdata<-getURL('http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2012/games.htm')
bdata<-htmlParse(bdata)
boxdata<-xpathSApply(bdata,'//a[contains(@href,"boxscore")]',xmlAttrs)[-1]
```

The above will get the boxscore stem for the various games.